# PhoneGap and JQ Mobile: Link specific section of external page

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

I have a two pages which are index.html(with few sections like #home and #level) and collection.html(#collection). When I am in collection.html I need to navigate back to index.html#level section it said "network error occured". Sometimes it worked and sometimes error occurred...

**collection.html**

```
<a href="index.html#level" rel="external" data-role="button" data-icon="back" >Back</a>
```

I am using Jquery mobile with phonegap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jquery Mobile overrides the standard `#anchor` behaviour. When navigating to `#anchor`, it expects to have a page DOM element with the Id `anchor`, and will transition to this page.
If you want a more standard behaviour, you can indicate `data-ajax="false"` in your `<a>` to disable the standard ajax navigation model (not recommended). Further information is available [here](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/docs/pages/page-links.html)

Answer (score 0):

One thing to be aware is on certain devices, paths are case sensitive. When run in the emulator, you wouldn't notice it. Make sure you are proper casing your hrefs to those of the filename.